# Redirect traffic to specific website

Tags: iptables, nat, forwarding, traffic

I am trying to setup something like a captive Portal but get stuck.
I have an embedded device which starts a Wireless Access Point. Now I like to forward all traffic to a website on the device. I do not want a login site to register and then you can use the internet, I only want to redirect to the single page. So if you enter google.de on your phone which is connected to the access point, the specific website should appear.

I looked at coovachilli and wifidog but they are too "big" for that, I only need a small part.

I tried [this](http://linux-aha.de/wordpress/2012/02/23/simpler-zugang-zum-netz-oder-nicht-captiveportal-in-einfach/), [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/708215/iptables-redirect-all-port-80-to-an-ip-but-let-one-ip-forwards-through) and [this](http://www.andybev.com/index.php/Using_iptables_and_PHP_to_create_a_captive_portal) but it did not work.
Here the error I get.

```
root:~> iptables  -N internet -t mangle
root:~> iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j internet
root:~> iptables -t mangle -A internet -j MARK --set-mark 99
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307480/iptables-all-traffic-forwarded-to-one-specific-ip) example I get no error, but entering google.de into the phone does not redirect to the specific site.

Do I need an extra kernel module for mask, or anywhere else some specific settings?